# Fixing errors in old DTM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, masking, nodata, gdal-calc

I'm currently working on fixing some errors in some old DTMs.

The issue is there are pixels with a value of "-1.4013e-45" which are all over the rasters. I'm looking for a way to remove these, as they're in areas where there should be NoData.

I have tried to generate a Mask, for valid pixels within the DTM, but the "-1.4013e-45" also get passed through, as they are within the range of valid pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

## 1 - r.mapcalc

`r.mapcalc "output_with_nodata = if(input_dem<=0.01, null(), input_dem)"`

## 2 - Save as + "no data" range

right-click on the layer name, `Export` -> `Save as`

then make sure you tick the `No data values` box, and enter a sensible range.
In your case it coul be for example (-1; 0.01)

[image]

## 3 - r.mapcalc.simple

A, well, simpler / GUI style `r.mapcalc`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it's something I can work with! I still don't understand why DTM's are output to greater than 4 decimal places, it makes no sense. Thanks again!!